# Query to output not existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Table A:

```
   id   Name
    1   a
    2   b
    3   c
    4   d
    5   e
```

Table B:

```
id  Name
3   c
4   d
5   e
```

Here, id is the primary key connected to Table B.

I need output like this:-

```
id 
1
2
```

That means, which ids in Table A are not present in Table B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `EXCEPT` operator:

```
select id from tableA
except
select id from tableB
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Not in` statement.

Try this:-

```
Select id from TableA
where id not in (Select id from TableB);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `left join`, which will preserve all records on the left side and associate them with `null` if no matching record is available on the right side.
This way you can then filter on the right side columns to be null to get the desired outcome

```
select  t1.id
from    tableA t1
left join
        tableB t2
on      t1.id = t2.id
where   t2.id is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Use NOT EXISTS in WHERE clause

```
  SELECT id FROM TableA A 
  WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TableB B WHERE A.id = B.Id )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minus`:

```
select * from tableA 
minus 
select * from tableB
```

Comment: `MINUS` is non-standard and only available in some DBMS (Oracle, Teradata, ...). SQL Server uses the standard `EXCEPT` instead.